# cannot use curl in AWS CodeBuild project: exit status 127 command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, curl, amazon-codebuild

It happens in post_build phase.

- Tried to install first, but was already installed.
- Tried to export PATH to include /usr/bin (where curl is installed)

```
[Container] 2023/11/28 16:44:10.462047 Running command ls -la $(which curl)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 260328 Oct  3 17:15 /usr/bin/curl

[Container] 2023/11/28 16:44:10.517469 Running command echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin/sbt/bin:/root/.goenv/shims:/root/.goenv/bin:/go/bin:/root/.phpenv/shims:/root/.phpenv/bin:/root/.pyenv/shims:/root/.pyenv/bin:/root/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/rbenv/bin:/usr/local/rbenv/shims:/root/.dotnet/:/root/.dotnet/tools/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/tools:/codebuild/user/bin

Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command:(...) Reason: exit status 127
```

Comment: could you share more details, which image you're using? and which cmd caused the error?

Comment: Sorry for late answer.

Image: Ubuntu 22.04 - standard 7
Command: curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way I was executing the command:

```
echo "$DATA" | gzip -c | curl -X POST -H "$AK" -H "$CT" "$URL" --data-binary @-
```

(works in shell - bash)

the fix was:

```
    - temp=$(mktemp)
    - $(echo "$DATA" | gzip -c > "$temp")
    - 'curl -X POST -H "Api-Key: $LK" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" "$URL" --data-binary "@$temp"'
    - rm -rf "$temp"
```